# Android: JSON string data compare with other string

Tags: android, json, string, compare

I would like to compare string from mysql database using JSON with my string.
I recieved data from database and Log shows that I have all data.

```
try{
     JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
     for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
         json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
         Log.i("mylog","TABLE_NAME: "+json_data.getString("table_name"));//returns cars

         if (  json_data.getString("table_name") == "cars" ) { //dosent work
              .... 
         }
     }
} catch(JSONException e){
         Log.e("mylog", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
     return false;
}
```

and in this example in Log I recieved name of table: cars
And below IF condition doesnt work and I have no idea WHY.
It is strange. I've tried many ways.

Do you know what is the reason why I cannot compare table_name from JSON with simple String?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `.equals()` for compare two strings in java/android.

```
if (json_data.getString("table_name").equals("cars")) {  

         }
```

it compare Strings refrence so cant work...

when You use String literal then use `==`

and `==` only for primitive data types and here `String is Object` So use `.equals`

Comment: Thank you :) I just figure out this solution on other thread :)

Comment: what happens ? whats problem now?